# Inexplicable and unwanted space around parent div

Tags: html, css

Okay so here's my problem: i am trying to build a single-page portfolio/freelance website [illustrator/graphic designer with only very basic web design skills] which will later include a smooth scroll feature.
It contains a fixed navbar at the top [grey rectangle], and i have 4 different sections/divs [black rectangles], contained inside a content parent div [red rectangle]. I've been literally killing myself to find a way to have my content parent div stretch 100% in width [height would be good to but i'm less worried about that] but for some reason there is that tiny EXTRA SPACE [green area] all around *no matter what I try.*

Here is my **HTML:**

```
<body>
    <div id="main">
        <div class="container clearfix">        
            <div id="navbar">
                <div id="nav-anchor"></div>
                <nav>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#about"><img src="../ALJUNxMILJUN/version-1.png" height="45px" /></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#services">Services</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
            <div id="content">
                <section id="about">blah blah blah</section>
                <section id="portfolio">blah blah blah</section>
                <section id="services">blah blah blah</section>
                <section id="contact">blah blah blah</section>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

And here is my **CSS** for the problematic part [navigation CSS not included cos it's not causing any problems]:

```
#content {
    width:100%;
    padding:0;
    margin: 52px 0 0 0;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

#about {
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 760px;
}

#portfolio {
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 760px;
}

#services {
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 760px;
}

#contact {
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 760px;
}
```

this is how my code/css looks like right now, stripped down to the basic.
at some point parent did have 100% width and did stretch but then i did something and can't seem to figure out what.

Comment: Add: html, body {
    margin:0;
} Default page margin causes tiny extra space (if you mean on that space, actually)

Comment: Further to the comment by @nevermind you should be using `* { margin:0; padding:0; }` at the top of your stylesheet to get rid of corss-browser default margin/padding issues on different elements.

Comment: THANK YOU!

i knew that page has a default margin but i was confused and thought that's not it because i had no problem for the navigation....i'll make sure to remember that.

Comment: Thanks @Adam, I'll see to fix that